# Javascript: Convert numbers inside the string

Tags: javascript

Im working on a simple conversation form, where I need to input dimensions ex. 12x24x36 inches to 304.8 x 609.6 x 914.4 mm.

My problem is I don't know how to compute convert those numbers separately.

I manage to remove the *x* but all the numbers merge.

Thanks, I hope you understand me.

here is my sample code

**HTML**

```
<h4>Dimensions</h4>
<label>inches <input id="number1"></label>
<label>mm <input id="number2"></label>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">convert</button>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
var inches = document.getElementById("number1").value;

  var removex = inches.replace(/x/g,"");

  var input = parseInt(removex);

document.getElementById("number2").value = input
}
```

**CODEPEN**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPpmej

Comment: Look at the [string `.split()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).`.inches.split("x")` gives you an array of the numbers. Or if you want to use regex I'd match on the numbers, not on the x's: `inches.match(/\d+/g)`.

Comment: You would need to split on something, be it a whitespace or an `X`. You need to decide on the desired input, validate to ensure that only valid input is specified, clearly state the input requirement, and then calculate based on the split.

Comment: thank you sir, I got the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a string like:

```
 var str = '304.8 x 609.6 x 914.4 mm'
```

You can use `split()` and `parseFloat()` to get an array of numbers with:

```js
var str = '304.8 x 609.6 x 914.4 mm'
var numbers = str.split('x').map(parseFloat)
console.log(numbers)
```

You just need to know your input format so you can adjust for other variations.

`parseFloat()` will ignore any non-numeric characters after the numbers so it works well for stripping units.

Answer (score 1):

If your receiving **"12x24x36" as input(string)** then  for complete desired result update your function as below:-

```js
function myFunction() {
  var inches = document.getElementById("number1").value;
  var inchesArr = inches.split("x");
  var mmArr = inchesArr.map(function(i) {
    return parseFloat(i) * 25.4;
  });
  var mmString = mmArr.join("x");

  document.getElementById("number2").value = mmString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EXPLANATION**

You can convert your input example `12x24x36` into an array via `str.split('x')`, then do the math conversion from inch to millimeters (x inches * 25.4) and push those back into a new array of millimeters values. Then you can rejoin those values with an x via `str.join('x')` and put them back into your document. Here's what it looks like.

**SCRIPT**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var inches = document.getElementById("number1").value.split('x');
  var millimeters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inches.length; i++) millimeters.push(parseInt(inches[i]*25.4));
  document.getElementById("number2").value = millimeters.join('x');
}
```

**CODEPEN**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyZOYb